# Testing a Spring MVC Handler interceptor with a session scoped bean dependency

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a problem I'm not able to solve. I have searched on the internet and on Stackoverflow but could not find how to solve the problem.

I want to test a Spring MVC Handler interceptor. This interceptor has a "session" scope bean as a dependency.

I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. Here is the code:

The src part :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "..." })
public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry interceptorRegistry) {
        interceptorRegistry.addInterceptor(initializeUserLanguageHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public InitializeUserLanguageHandler initializeUserLanguageHandler() {
        return new InitializeUserLanguageHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public SessionBean sessionBean() {
        return new SessionBean();
    }
}


@Component
public class InitializeUserLanguageHandler extends AbstractHandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (sessionBean.getLanguage() == null) {
            sessionBean.setLanguage(getUserLanguage());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The test part:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringMvcConfiguration.class)
public class BaseSpringMvcIntegrationTest {

    @Resource
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
}

public class InitializeUserLanguageHandlerTest extends BaseSpringMvcIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    @Autowired
    private MockHttpSession mockHttpSession;

    @Test
    public void testLanguageIsInitializedOnlyOnce() throws Exception {
        MockHttpSession mocksession = new MockHttpSession();

        // It is null, this is because the interceptor has not been called yet
        assertEquals(null, sessionBean.getLanguage());

        // This line will call the interceptor and set language to "nl"
        mockMvc.perform(get("/").session(mocksession).principal(getUser("nl")));

        // It is null, but I expect it to be "nl" 
        assertEquals(null, sessionBean.getLanguage()); 

        // Let's try again     
        mockMvc.perform(get("/").session(mocksession).principal(getUser("fr")));

        // It is null, but I expect it to be "nl" 
        assertEquals(null, sessionBean.getLanguage());
    }
}
```

You can see in the test class "InitializeUserLanguageHandlerTest" that I have some assertions.

The first time I call:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/").session(mocksession).principal(getUser()));
```

The code in the interceptor is executed and language is set to "nl". Therefore, in my test, I would have expected that sessionBean.getLanguage() would return me "nl", but it is not. I don't understand why.

So I'm calling the perform again, the interceptor code is executed again, and calling sessionBean.getLanguage() returns "nl".

It seems I've two SessionBean instances, one in my test and the other in the source. But when I look at the SessionBean variable in Eclipse in Debug mode, they have the same ID.

If I change the "session" scope to "application" scope, it is working properly.

Can somebody help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem, not sure it is the best though.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMvcConfiguration.class, InitializeUserLanguageHandlerTest.BeanConfig.class})
public class InitializeUserLanguageHandlerTest extends BaseSpringMvcIntegrationTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class BeanConfig {
        @Bean(name = "sessionBean")
        public SessionBean sessionBean() {
            return new SessionBean();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```